# python openpyxl skip header of excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

Hi I am iterating through lines, from few answers in the forum and using row_offset=1 but it is not skipping the header, please check and help.

### Code

```
> import openpyxl
> 
> Owb= openpyxl.load_workbook("E:\\First.xlsx") Ows = Owb.worksheets[0]
> 
> row_counter=1
> 
> for row in Ows.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
> 
>     policy_number=Ows.cell(row=row_counter,column=1).value
>     print policy_number
>     Ows.cell(row=row_counter, column=2).value = "test value"
> 

>     row_counter = row_counter + 1
>     Owb.save("E:\\First.xlsx")
```

Comment: Is `openpyxl` a requirement, or are you willing to use another library (e.g. `pandas`)?

Comment: Why are you using both `iter_rows` and `cell` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problem with your code:

1. Even though you have provided row offset, you are still using
   row_counter which starts from 1
2. You should be iterating over all the cells in
       the row

#### Soln

Why don't you just start from the second row.

```
import openpyxl

Owb= openpyxl.load_workbook("E:\\First.xlsx") 
Ows = Owb.worksheets[0]

for rowno, rowval in enumerate(Ows.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=Ows.max_row), start=2):
    for cell in rowval:
        policy_number=Ows.cell(row=rowno,column=1).value
        print policy_number
        Ows.cell(row=rowno, column=2).value = "test value"

Owb.save("E:\First.xlsx")
```

Comment: thank for observations and feedback , after trying the solution there was a error ------    raise ValueError("Row or column values must be at least 1")
ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1

Comment: But when I add 2 in rowno it giving me the solution what i needed. as below

Comment: policy_number=Ows.cell(row=rowno+2, column=1).value    and same in writing cell Ows.cell(row=rowno+2, column=2).value="test"

Comment: Ohh yea sorry, made the necessary changes